# Moving the function to the right does not work

Tags: r, plot

I made Gaussian mixture model, it works fine, but the function is not moving to the right. In the graph it shows as if the function did not move anything. I incorporated a for loop for the `mu`:

```
for(i in 1:n){
  for (j in 1:5){
    mu1 = c(1+j,2)
    mu2 = c(6+j,7) 
    .
    .
    .
     }
     }
```

but it doesn't work. I try to obtain a graphic as it appears in the image: that it moves at the same time as the previous thing is saved, covering more and more space

```
library(MASS)


n = 1000
Sigma = matrix(c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 1), 2, 2)
rho = 0.5

# Gaussian mixture model
# X=(X1,X2) ~ rho * N(mu1, Sigma) + (1-rho) * N(mu2, Sigma)
X = cbind(rep(0, n), rep(0, n))
for(i in 1:n){
  for (j in 1:5){
    mu1 = c(1+j,2)
    mu2 = c(6+j,7)
    u = runif(1, min = 0, max = 1)
    if(u < rho){
      X[i,] = mvrnorm(1, mu = mu1, Sigma = Sigma)
    }else{
      X[i,] = mvrnorm(1, mu = mu2, Sigma = Sigma)
    }
  }
}

plot(X[,1], X[,2], xlab = 'X1', ylab = 'X2')
```

[image]

Comment: It seems like in your inner loop the `X[i, ]` row gets overwritten at each iteration. What's the point of the `j` loop?

Comment: I also don't understand *"I try to obtain a graphic as it appears in the image: that it moves at the same time as the previous thing is saved, covering more and more space"*. Do you mean you want an animated plot? Or a series of plots? Or a single plot that shows progress over time?

Comment: I try to save each of the 5 iterations in X [i,]` owhen I iterate over `mu`. That the data of the distributions is saved when `mu` is shifted to the right

Comment: @GregorThomas, a single plot that shows progress over time

Comment: When `i` is 1, `j` has values 1,2,3,4,5 at different iterations. But for all 5 `j` values  there is only one `i` value, so `X[i,]` will only have the result from `j = 5`---`X[i,]` gets overwritten each time.

Comment: If you can help me understand the goal of your code more, I can help more. You have `n = 1000`, and you set up `X` to be a 2x1000 matrix. Because your loop is nested, with 1000 iterations of the outer loop and 5 iterations of the inner loop, you generate 5000 `mu` values and call `mvrnorm` 5000 times. So, do you want to save a plot 1000 rows or 5000 rows?

Comment: I want to save a plot 5000 rows. I try to make `X` have 2 columns and 5000 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've adjusted your code to save all 5000 rows:

```
n = 1000  
m = 5
Sigma = matrix(c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 1), 2, 2)
rho = 0.5

library(MASS)
# Gaussian mixture model
# X=(X1,X2) ~ rho * N(mu1, Sigma) + (1-rho) * N(mu2, Sigma)
X = cbind(rep(0, n * m), rep(0, n * m))
for(i in 1:n){
  for (j in 1:m){
    mu1 = c(1+j,2)
    mu2 = c(6+j,7)
    u = runif(1, min = 0, max = 1)
    if(u < rho){
      X[(i - 1) * m + j,] = mvrnorm(1, mu = mu1, Sigma = Sigma)
    }else{
      X[(i - 1) * m + j,] = mvrnorm(1, mu = mu2, Sigma = Sigma)
    }
  }
}

plot(X[,1], X[,2], xlab = 'X1', ylab = 'X2')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @GregorThomar. I don't really understand how this part works `X[(i - 1) * m + j,]`. Could you explain me please? I tried to understand it, but I couldn't

Comment: Let's do a small example: Imagine a nested loop set `n <- 3; m <- 4` and loop `for(i in 1:n) { for(j in 1:m) { print(...)  }}`. The puzzle is to put something inside `...` that will print 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ..., 12. This is the solution to that puzzle. We need that sequence so that every sub-iteration has a unique value, so we can store it in a unique row of `X`. My best advice for understanding it is to experiment. `print(i)` `print(j)` at every iteration, experiment, and it will make sense.

Comment: The alternate way is to use a separate `counter`, something like `counter <- 1` before the loop, assign to `X[counter, ] <- ...` and then put `counter <- counter + 1` immediately after the assignment.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help